# Regex to replace word except in comments

Tags: regex

How can I modify my regex so that it will ignore the comments in the pattern in a language that doesn't support lookbehind?

My regex pattern is:

```
\b{Word}\b(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)
```

- \b{Word}\b : Whole word, {word} is replaced iteratively for the vocab list
- (?=([^""\]*(\.|""([^""\]*\.)*[^""\]*""))*[^""]*$) : Don't replace anything inside of quotes

My goal is to lint variables and words so that they always have the same case. However I do not want to lint any words in a comment. (The IDE sucks and there is no other option)

Comments in this language are prefixed by an apostrophe. Sample code follows

```
' This is a comment
This = "Is not" ' but this is 
' This is a comment, what is it's value?
Object.value = 1234 ' Set value
value = 123
```

Basically I want the linter to take the above code and say for the word "value" update it to:

```
' This is a comment
This = "Is not" ' but this is 
' This is a comment, what is it's value?
Object.Value = 1234 ' Set value
Value = 123
```

So that all code based "Value" are updated but not anything in double quotes or in a comment or part of another word such as valueadded wouldn't be touched.

I've tried several solutions but haven't been able to get it to work.

- ['.*] : Not preceeding an apostrophy
- (?<!\s*') : BackSearch not with any spaces with apoostrophy
- (?<!\s*') : Second example seemed incorrect but this won't work as the language doesn't support backsearches

Anybody have any ideas how I can alter my pattern so that I don't edit commented variables

VBA

```
Sub TestSO()
    Dim Code As String
    Dim Expected As String
    Dim Actual  As String
    Dim Words   As Variant
    Code = "item = object.value ' Put item in value" & vbNewLine & _
              "some.item <> some.otheritem" & vbNewLine & _
              "' This is a comment, what is it's value?" & vbNewLine & _
              "Object.value = 1234 ' Set value" & vbNewLine & _
              "value = 123" & vbNewLine

    Expected = "Item = object.Value ' Put item in value" & vbNewLine & _
              "some.Item <> some.otheritem" & vbNewLine & _
              "' This is a comment, what is it's value?" & vbNewLine & _
              "Object.Value = 1234 ' Set value" & vbNewLine & _
              "Value = 123" & vbNewLine
    
    Words = Array("Item", "Value")
    Actual = SOLint(Words, Code)
    Debug.Print Actual = Expected
    Debug.Print "CODE: " & vbNewLine & Code
    Debug.Print "Actual: " & vbNewLine & Actual
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & vbNewLine & Expected
    
End Sub
Public Function SOLint(ByVal Words As Variant, ByVal FileContents As String) As String
    Const NotInQuotes  As String = "(?=([^""\\]*(\\.|""([^""\\]*\\.)*[^""\\]*""))*[^""]*$)"
    Dim RegExp      As Object
    Dim Regex    As String
    Dim Index       As Variant
    
    
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    For Each Index In Words
        Regex = "[('*)]\b" & Index & "\b" & NotInQuotes
        RegExp.Pattern = Regex
    
        FileContents = RegExp.Replace(FileContents, Index)
    Next Index
    
    SOLint = FileContents
End Function
```

Comment: ` (?:\".*\")|(?:'.*)|(value) ` - It captures "value" string outside of " " and also '. Is this what u r looking for ? https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/4

Comment: That doesn't seem quite right, when I pass this through a replace function I loose the comments. Ideally I want to replace the value in place with the regex. But it does look much closer. I'll try to play around with that and see if I can make it do things I need.

Comment: In which language are you trying this ? Can you please paste the code ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/7 - I changed it again. Is this ok ? You can check the substitution section to see the expected output.

Comment: I think the only change would be ((?:\".*\")|(?:'.*))|\b(v)(alue)\b adding the \b so that valueadded doesn't get picked up. That seems to work. I haven't fully tested it, can you explain the replacement, I'm not sure I understand how the grouping is working on that one. This solution would mean I would need to do some work on the words, but it seems to be it. I'll add a code update shortly

Comment: Ok I dint know that you dont want valueadded text even though it is outside of single or double quotes. In that case I updated it again....https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/8

Comment: As an FYI, If you haven't noticed, there is replacement text also in the link I shared.

Comment: Okay I understand. Instead of replacing the text which would affect all groups, it's converting the case of the group directly without replacing what is already there. I can work with this @rootkonda. You should make this an answer so that I can accept it at the end of the week.

Comment: ok great I will . Interesting question !

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above:

```
((?:\".*\")|(?:'.*))|\b(v)(alue)\b
```

3 Parts to this regex used with alternation.

1. A non-capturing group for text within double quotes, as we dont need that.
2. A non-capturing group for text starting with single quote
3. Finally the string "value" is split into two parts (v) and (value) because while replacing we can use \U($2) to convert v to V and rest as is so \E$3 where \U - converts to upper case and \E - turns off the case.
4. \b \b - word boundaries are used to avoid any stand-alone text which is not part of setting a value.

https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/8